# Attach to running process in windows

Tags: windows, powershell, c#

I am working with application A, which I launch in the terminal. Before Process A finishes to run, it launches process B on a separate terminal.

From this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43914800/attach-to-running-program-with-powershell, I know I am unable to attach to process B once it starts running, without a debugger(Which I don't want to do for performance reasons).

However, unlike the scenario presented in a post, I know in advance that A will launch B. Given that, is there a way for me to attach the current PowerShell session to process B(spawned child process)?

Comment: What is it from process A you are trying to accomplish from process B exactly? Are you trying to tell if the process is still running or finished and was killed, etc. or something more?

Comment: No, I just want to attach the current terminal to process B so I can monitor STDOUT until process B dies. But I don't have control over process A (in terms of its' configuration). I just know that process A launches process B, and then exits, while process B remains running.

Comment: So you have control over process B in terms of configuration then? Can process B stdout just go to a file and you can actively monitor the stout from the file from the terminal you use to monitor it? Process B should have a pid and you have current time so you could use some standard naming convention for the std out using those in with it so you know which to monitor using conditional logic with `datetime -le` or something like that. So file `20211224_003815_4456.tmp` could be stdout for process B and you can read from it actively with terminal commands, etc. You said you know when A launches

Comment: Meaning `<YYYYDDMM>_<HHMMSS>_<pid>.tmp` and you know when Process A starts so you could build some conditional from your terminal to capture the stdout around the start or execution start time of Process A.

Comment: <YYYYDDMM>_<HHMMSS> is what I ended up doing, however, it didn't occur to me that I could also add pid to it, this allows me to easier track executable(like checking if I should still monitor the file, even after the process completed the execution). Thanks for your input!